# Unable to debug using PhpStorm with EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, phpstorm, remote-debugging

I am trying to configure PhpStorm on my local machine and repository is on Amazon EC2. I used SSH tunnelling also but unable to debug using remote debugger.

Here are my configuration files I have placed same configuration in

```
/etc/php-5.6.d/xdebug.ini
/etc/php.ini

zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1                 ; Enable xdebug
xdebug.remote_autostart=Off             ; Only start xdebug on demand, not on every request
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1      ; This is unused if the next setting is 'On'
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=On           ; Use a special $_SERVER['...'] variable to get the remote address
xdebug.remote_port=9002                 ; Port on the IDE to connect back to. Usually it is 9000
xdebug.idekey="phpstorm"                ; The IDE key which should match the XDEBUG_SESSION cookie valu
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug_remote_log.log"
xdebug.extended_info=1e
```

[image: PhpStorm configuration]

[image]

I'm creating SSH tunnel using the command given below

```
ssh -R 9002:localhost:9002 root@18.2xx.2xx.1xx
```

After turning off remote_connect_back the new logs are here

```
Log opened at 2018-04-23 15:59:32
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9002.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/immunedata-prod/immunedata/website-php/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.6.32" protocol_version="1.0" appid="15683" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.5.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2017 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2018-04-23 15:59:32
```

How to resolve this issue, I'm not using port 9000 because there's another microservice running at that port.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel

Comment: 1) In one place you are stating 9002, in another -- 9000 (mainly the difference in xdebug log and your settings). 2) If you using SSH tunnel .. you better be connecting to 127.0.0.1. With `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` the value of `xdebug.remote_host` is ignored (that's what xdebug log confirms) 3) Tunnel is for 9000 .. but IDE is listening on 9002... Overall: double check your settings and what values are used where -- follow the article in first comment and use consistent values in both places (so less chance for an error).

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you, I posted wrong ssh command here I was tunneling with port 9002 , logs I think posted older ones, I will check those and will update the question

Comment: @LazyOne I have updated logs, you can see all settings are now pointing to port 9002

Comment: Re-check #2 again. You are using SSH tunnel .. so on your remote server ... you need to connect to their local port so it get passed through the tunnel back to your local PC. Based on xdebug log Xdebug tries to connect to `192.147.26.229:9002` .. while it should be `127.0.0.1:9002` (unless they both point to the same server). You have `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` -- with this option `On/1` the `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1` setting is IGNORED. So .. set that option to be `Off/0` and try again.

Comment: In meantime you may check if SSH tunnel is working: Ensure that PhpStorm is listening for incoming debug connections (e.g. that "phone handle" icon is ON); Login to remote PC via SSH and try to connect to the tunnel via telnet (connect to 127.0.0.1:9002). If tunnel/PhpStorm is setup correctly then telnet connection will succeed.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for your suggestions after turning off remote_connect_back it's trying to connect to localhost, but its getting failed with this error "connect_to 127.0.0.1 port 9002: failed.
setsockopt TCP_NODELAY: Invalid argument
connect_to 127.0.0.1 port 9002: failed."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169608/discussion-between-namrutha-and-lazyone).

Comment: Try telnet as I have suggested (to check tunnel connectivity). Maybe Amazon somehow blocks outgoing connections or stuff like that -- this needs to be checked first...

Comment: @LazyOne telnet is not working, I tried that

Comment: 1) Do you have "phone handle" icon active in PhpStorm when checking that? It has to be. 2) Is that PhpStorm that listens on 9002 port on your local PC? 3) Other than that -- maybe SSH tunnel is not established properly. No better ideas.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you for your help, after I changed port to 9000 on both phpstorm and xdebug it's working, it was some issue with ec2 port configurations.