# Unable to get Xdebug working with EC2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm attempting to get Xdebug connecting to my PhpStorm from an EC2 instance.

- I have opened up port 9000 on the security group tied to the EC2 instance.
- Prior to opening it up with UDP, I would get:

  ````
  telnet: connect to address <IP>: Connection refused
  telnet: Unable to connect to remote host```
  ````
- After opening it up, I get:
  `Trying <IP>...` and it just hangs there.
- I port forwarded 9020 internally to 9000 externally to see if that would give any different results (since I can't find a setting on the router for simply opening up ports)
- My xdebug.ini setting is located at: /etc/php-5.6.d/50-xdebug.ini (yes, very old version of PHP that I have to work with here).
- My xdebug.ini contains this:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
```

- I'm using PhpStorm, and have it listening on port 9020 now (tried 9000 prior to port forwarding with the same result).
- I have the Xdebug browser extension installed and have it set to PHPSTORM.
- I have stop on first line turned on, as well as breakpoints just in case.
- Xdebug is set to listen.

When I hit the PHP page from my browser, nothing happens. I've had this working dozens of times, but never from an EC2 instance. Any idea what I missed?

Comment: Just in case: 1) it's xdebug that makes connection to IDE and not other way around .. so it has to be outgoing connection on Amazon, not incoming. 2) What Xdebug log has to say about this? You may be connecting to the wrong IP...

Comment: Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968159/unable-to-debug-using-phpstorm-with-ec2

Comment: Ok, #1 is taken care of. All outgoing is open. I was just making sure it wasn't the other way around, trying to cover all of my bases. Next I'll check the xdebug log.

Comment: #2, there is no xdebug log

Comment: With `xdebug.remote_autostart=on` it should try to debug every single request. If it's not creating any log .. then it's not trying to debug... 1) double check your config from `phpinfo()` output captured via browser -- maybe post it here 2) Any SELinux or alike in place?

Comment: Yes, it did. I think I had the server IP set incorrectly in my configuration. Odd thing is, I had tried it with the domain name, and that hadn't worked. Now I disabled connect_back and autostart, and I did the tunnel as mentioned in the link you gave. Now it's actually working. I may play around with it later and see if I can get it working with the remote_connect_back, but for now I have something. Thank you!